# Iterate through the query and divide numbers into groups

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

I'm writing a script for the game. It should iterate through the query and print the group of numbers. In the every group, there are 9 numbers. For example, if `mysql_num_rows($sql_pp);` returns 16, everything should look like this:

1. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.
2. 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16.

---

My code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
Header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/data/conn_file.php");

$login = $_SESSION['login'];
$laukai = mysql_query("SELECT tb_pole.num, tb_pole.type, tb_pole.time AS tb_pole_time,
    tb_time.time AS tb_time_time FROM `tb_pole` JOIN tb_time ON tb_pole.type =
    tb_time.type WHERE `username` = '$login' ORDER BY tb_pole.time");
$sql_pp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tb_pole` WHERE `username` = '$login'") or
    die(mysql_error());
$kol_pole = mysql_num_rows($sql_pp);
$koll = $kol_pole / 9;

if ($kol_pole <= 8) {
    $kl = 1;
} else {
    $kl = 1;
    while ($kl <= $koll) {
        $kl++;
    }
}
?>
<table>
<?php
if (mysql_num_rows($laukai) > 0) {
    for ($i = 1; $i<=$kl; $i++) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($laukai))  {
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['num']; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

It shows this: [image]

As you can see, the last row is `1 | 10`. It should be `2 | 10` (because number 10 is in the group 2) (changed from `1` to `2` using "inspect element")
[image]

---

I was using these lines of code when my variable `$i` wasn't in the `while` loop:

```
<div id="tabs_pole">
<ul>
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= $kl; $i++) {
?>
        <li><a href="#pole<?=$i; ?>"><span><?=$i; ?></span></a></li>
<?php
    }
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

And everything was working fine: [image].
How can I achieve that using the `while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution :) Thank you, everyone, for the help :)

```
switch (true) {
case ($row['num'] <= 9):
    $i = 1;
    break;
case ($row['num'] <= 9 * 2):
    $i = 2;
    break;
case ($row['num'] <= 9 * 3):
    $i = 3;
    break;
case ($row['num'] <= 9 * 4):
    $i = 4;
    break;
case ($row['num'] <= 9 * 5):
    $i = 5;
    break;
case ($row['num'] <= 9 * 6):
    $i = 6;
    break;
case ($row['num'] <= 9 * 7):
    $i = 7;
    break;
case ($row['num'] <= 9 * 8):
    $i = 8;
    break;
}
```